# gvim window looks bad

Tags: gvim, linux, font

[image]

I don't know why my gvim windows looks like this in linux. Is there anything I need to add to my vimrc file in addition to this?

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set nocompatible
set number
set numberwidth=1
set autoindent
set backspace=2
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set shellslash
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
filetype indent on
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
imap ^[OA <ESC>ki
imap ^[OB <ESC>ji
imap ^[OC <ESC>li
imap ^[OD <ESC>hi
augroup markdown
    au!
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.md,*.markdown setlocal filetype=ghmarkdown
augroup END
colorscheme koehler 
set guifont=Consolas\ 12
set guioptions-=T "remove toolbar
if !has("gui_running")
    set guioptions=icpM
    set term=xterm
    set t_Co=256
    let &t_AB="\e[48;5;%dm"
    let &t_AF="\e[38;5;%dm"
    inoremap <Char-0x07F> <BS>
    nnoremap <Char-0x07F> <BS>
    colorscheme koehler 
endif
```

[image]

**DIFFERENCE - left one is terminal and right side is gvim**
I didn't have this problem in windows 10

Answer (score 10):

The problem is probably that you don't have the Consolas font installed and that Vim defaults to an ugly default font.

Try using a different font, for example this should work on most Linux systems:

```
set guifont=Dejavu\ Sans\ Mono\ 12
```

If you want it to work on both Windows and Linux you can use something like:

```
if has('gui_gtk')
    set guifont=Dejavu\ Sans\ Mono\ 12
else
    set guifont=Consolas:h12
endif
```

Or, if you want to use Consolas on Linux, [you can install it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/310412/33645).

Comment: worked pretty well. Thank you for the reply (very useful)

Comment: As an alternative to the Consolas font one can use Inconsolata which is pretty similar. It's free (as in free beer) and available on most Linux distrutions repositories

Comment: By the way, you can accept answers by pressing the tick next to the voting arrows, which makes it easier to find for other people with your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RHEL7, it might be that you don't have gui fonts installed, especially if you started with a server.  Try:

```
# yum groupinstall fonts
```

A lot of the responses to stack exchange threads involve something about saying that the default GVIM font looks bad if you don't have certain fonts installed. So I just installed the yum group package for fonts and it worked. Probably the same for other distros too, especially if you started with a server build without a gui.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Could you explain why not having gui fonts installed would cause this issue?

Comment: A lot of the responses to these threads involve something about saying that the default GVIM font looks bad if you don't have certain fonts installed.  So I just installed the yum group package for fonts and it worked.

Comment: feel free to [edit] that in!