# Change a font in Vim/GVim in a simple way

Tags: gvim, linux, font

I merely want to change a font in Vim/GVim. That's it. This doesn't work:

```
font=Monaco\ 14
```

I've done a google search and I wonder, why is for such a elementary task there's no simple answer which works, instead I've found a lot of ambiguous, complex solutions. And none of them worked.  How can I do that?

Comment: Which OS? What you can use depends on the OS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading the `'guifont'` option is useful here. I do understand your frustrations with this option however. It seems that how you set the `'guifont'` setting, is dependent on the OS.

On macOS, you set 'guifont' the following way (which is noted in [:help 'guifont'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27guifont%27)):

```
set guifont=Monaco:h14
```

On other OSes (Linux, etc) you use the backslash instead to specify the font size:

```
set guifont=Monaco\ 14
```

Another useful way to set the font is to use `:set guifont=*` which will bring up the Font chooser for your OS. Selecting a font then will apply it for your Gvim instance.

Why this distinction between the "\" and ":" to set the font size exists, however, is a separate question which I would like to know as well.

Comment: You also need to make sure the font exists; unfortunately gvim unhelpfully falls back to some ugly default font without giving an error if the font doesn't exist (like e.g. [this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9616/51)).

Comment: Yeah -- it seems to be it falls back on the standard Serif/UI font that you set for your WM. I don't know what's different about Macvim though that it gives you an error that the font doesn't exist.