# gvim looks terrible on my RedHat. Unable to change font

Tags: gvim, linux, font

When running gvim on my RedHat:

```
Linux trex-06 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 19 11:24:13 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.3 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.3"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.3 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.3:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.3
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.3"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
```

The spacing between letters is too wide which looks really bad.

[image]

I tried changing font (:set guifont=*) to monospace, and it stays exactly the same. Same goes for other fonts.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Probably the same as [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9616/51)? If you set an invalid `guifont` Vim will default to that ugly font. What did you set `guifont` to *exactly*? `set guifont=Dejavu\ Sans\ Mono\ 12` should work on most Linux systems (if not, try `Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono\ 12`).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker tried that of course. Only changes the font size. Also tried to select manually with set guifont=*. Perhaps no fonts installed at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out the fonts that

```
:set guifont=*
```

show are not installed.

No idea why gvim decides to show them. Might be a bug.

Also the suggestion [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9616/51) doesn't work. I believe that the font suggested is also not installed.

So a friend found:

```
:set guifont=Courier\ 10\ Pitch\ 13
```

Which works.