# gvim adds one extra pixel spacing after each character?

Tags: gvim, font

For some reason, gvim is adding one extra pixel of spacing after each character. It almost seems similar to [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13432/gvim-looks-terrible-on-my-redhat-unable-to-change-font), but in my case gvim does use the correct font.

I compared the same font in my terminal and gvim (see below, top = terminal, bottom = gvim, just for testing with an empty `.vimrc` file), the individual characters are identical (same font/width/height/..), but after each character there is an additional pixel of spacing. Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix this?

*Original size:*

[image]

*Enlarged:*

[image]

Comment: What OS? Which terminal? Terminals often display at lower effective resolution than GUI....but need to know your specifics.

Comment: Gnome terminal, Manjaro linux. I checked the same font in another text editor (Kate), and there the font looks the same as in the terminal..

Comment: Gnome is GTK based, isn't it? You're not using GTK themes (CSS) by any chance? I think that could be used to add padding to text in a specific app. But I'm _really_ reaching with that theory.